$|z+2|z-1||=|z-2|z+1||$ in Argand plane
IIT JEE(M, July, 2022) asked about the curve $$|z+|z-1||=|z-|z+1||$$ which represents either $y$ axis or a line segment: $-1\le x\le 1$, in the Argand plane.
The question is:
In Argand plane what does $$|z+2|z-1||=|z-2|z+1||$$ represent? What is its Cartesian form?

What have you tried so far? I think squaring both sides and expanding the terms would simplify the expression a lot.

Try : Take z=x+iy then expand using |z| property

Let $\overline{z}$ denote the complex conjugate of $z$. We have,
\begin{align*}
|z + 2|z-1||^2 & = |z - 2|z+1||^2 \\
\implies |z|^2 + 2|z-1|(z + \overline{z}) + 4|z - 1|^2 & = |z|^2 - 2|z+1|(z + \overline{z}) + 4|z + 1|^2 \\
\implies  2|z-1|(z + \overline{z}) + 4(|z|^2 - (z + \overline{z}) + 1) & = - 2|z+1|(z + \overline{z}) + 4(|z|^2 + (z + \overline{z}) + 1) \\
\implies 2 \cdot (z + \overline{z}) \cdot (|z-1| + |z+1| - 4) & = 0.
\end{align*}
Consequently,

Either $(z + \overline{z}) = 0$, i.e., $z$ is purely imaginary, or ,equivalently lies on the $y$ axis.
Or, $|z-1| + |z+1| = 4$, i.e., $z$ lies on an ellipse centered at the origin and whose length of major axis is $4$ and foci are on the points $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$.


Yes, it is either $y$ axis or an ellipse
$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}=4$$
which can be put in a more interesting and simple form
by denoting LHS as $$\sqrt{P}+\sqrt{Q}=4 \cdots (1)$$, then
we get $$P-Q=4x \cdots (2)$$ and
$$\sqrt{P}-\sqrt{Q}=x \cdots (3)$$
Adding (1) and (2), we get
$$2\sqrt{P}=4+x \implies 4(x+1)^2+4y^2=(4+x)^2.$$
Which up on simplification gives
$$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{3}=1.$$
